# PHP Streaming no metadata when seek at a position

Tags: actionscript-3, netstream, pseudo-streaming

I am using PHP to stream video file everything is working until a try to start from a position
the problem that when i load the video file with a start position for example

ns.play('flvprovider.php?file=video.flv&pos=156212');

it will seek but i will not receive the metadata, i know that the metadata are injected at the head of the video file that's propobaly why i can't get the metadata when i load the video from a position but i wont to know if there a solution to get arround this problem
below the provider that i use

```
    set_time_limit(0);
// ----- NO CACHE -----
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
// General header for no caching
$now = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT';
header('Expires: ' . $now); // rfc2616 - Section 14.21
header('Last-Modified: ' . $now);
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // HTTP/1.0

// ----- Seek position -----
$seekat = 0;
if( isset($_GET["pos"])) 
{
    $seekat = intval($_GET["pos"]);
    if ($seekat < 0) $seekat = 0;
}

// ----- file -----
$filename = "";
if( isset($_GET["video"])) 
{
    $filename = htmlspecialchars($_GET["video"]);
}
else
{
    $filename = 'media/philosophie1-inj.flv';
}
$ext = strrchr($filename, ".");
// to hide the video file. For example: $prefix = "hide_" 
// to get the video file in a directory. For example: $prefix = "videos/" 
$prefix = "";
$file = $prefix . $filename;

if (($filename != "") && (file_exists($file)) && ($ext==".flv") || ($ext==".mp4")) 
{
    header("Content-Type: video/x-flv");
    //header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $filename . "\"");

    //Be sure to post the correct Content Length.
    if ($seekat > 0) header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($file)-$seekat));
    else header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));

    if ($seekat != 0) 
    {
        print("FLV");
        print(pack('C', 1 ));
        print(pack('C', 1 ));
        print(pack('N', 9 ));
        print(pack('N', 9 ));
    }
    $fh = fopen($file, "rb");
    fseek($fh, $seekat);
    while (!feof($fh)) 
    {
        //print (fread($fh, 16384));
         print (fread($fh, filesize($file)));
    }
    fclose($fh);
}
else 
{
    print("<html><body>");
    print("Page not found.");
    print("</body></html>");
}
```

Thanks you !!